# Clickonce don't want load assembly

Tags: c#, clickonce

We have a application that load dynamically a library/assembly (mysql.dll) need for our report engine.

The app work fine if we copy the folder or in debug but when we deploy the app via Click once, the assembly is not loaded.

What's the issue? We think it's a security issue .

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project->Properties->Publish Tab. In the publish tab go to Application Files and make sure that the publish status is set to "Include".